# Returning JSON from WCF Web API

Tags: wcf-web-api

The WCF Web API returns data either XML or JSON based on the Accept parameter in the request header not considering whether we set ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json in the WebInvoke/WebGet attributes. Is this the correct behavior of the API or a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF Web API ignores the ResponseFormat attribute.  That attribute is just there because of an effort to be backward compatible with previous WCF REST efforts.
The returned media type is based largely on the Accept header sent by the client.

Comment: Is it possible to ignore the Accept header and return always a particular media type (like JSON) from server?

Comment: @Mark If you return a HttpRequestMessage then you will have no problem. If you return a DTO it would be a bit more tricky. If you return an ObjectContent<T> you can pass a mediatype to the constructor.

Comment: @Mark You could clear/remove MediaTypeFormatters so that only the one you wanted remained.

Comment: @OffBySome can you plz post some code sample about how to clear/remove mediatypeformatters and always return JSON from server

Comment: @Mark, another option is to add a message handler that changes the Accept header on the request.

Comment: @Mark: Look at GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters to see a list of default MediaTypeFormatters. It has three types by default.